# one normal distribution problem

Tags: normal-distribution

A rice bag advertises that it contains 1 kg rice, the machine that pours the rice is not able to pour exact 1000 gm rice each time, rather the actual weight of the rice which follows the normal distribution with mean and standard deviation 18,

1. Suppose that the machine is set so that the weights have a mean of 1015 gram, what is the prob that a randomly selected bag of rice than the advertised on the bag?
2. what mean value the machine be set so that it is expected that 1% of the bag will be under-weight?

(1) If the weight $X$ of a randomly poured bag of rice is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma = 18$, then the probability that $X < 1000$ is $$\Pr[X < 1000] = \Pr\left[\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} < \frac{1000 - \mu}{18}\right].$$  If the machine is set so that $\mu = 1015$, then this probability becomes $$\Pr\left[\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{1000-1015}{18}\right] = \Pr[Z < -15/18],$$ where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$;

(2) Could any one help me to solve?

Comment: (1) Probability underweight is about 0.2. (2) If $\mu=1041.9,$ then this probability decreases of $0.00996 < 1\%.$ // You have recently asked several questions on this site that seem to be homework-style questions, but somewhat vaguely stated and without showing any of your own thoughts or preliminary work. That is contrary to the customs of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Question (2), you are asked to find out the value of $\mu$ so that
$\Phi(\frac{1000-\mu}{\sigma})=0.01$.